# In Erlang how can I import all functions from a module?

Tags: erlang

I can't figure out how to import all the functions of a module without having to specify the individual functions.

Comment: Parse transforms to the rescue? :-)

Comment: @Roberta. Do you mean why would I import functions or why would someone use parse transforms.

Comment: Why would you import all functions. BTW, why did you change sex to me? :)

Comment: Sorry Roberta, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I would import all the functions so that the module declaration would be less verbose.

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert, "The feminine version is Roberta. The Italian form is Roberto." ;)

BTW, importing all functions gives rise to interesting situations: if a function is added to the imported module, when there is already a function with the same name in the importing module, the importing module would become invalid despite not having changed at all.  And it could be a bit confusing :)

Comment: @Roberto. Ah! Sorry about that! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Christian says, "It is not possible to import all functions from a module." The compiler has no `import_all` directive and I think this is done deliberately to discourage excessive function importing.

Importing functions instead of fully qualifying them `M:F(...)` is usually bad style. There is a semantic difference between calling a module-local function and a function in another module (code-loading rules), so I think it's best to make foreign calls explicit. One could possibly make exceptions for importing dict/lists/sets module functions, as those are commonly understood and are unlikely to change during a code upgrade.

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible to import all functions from a module.

Answer (score 7):

Reading from the [Erlang Programming Rules](http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml#HDR26):

> Don't use -import, using it makes the
>   code harder to read since you cannot
>   directly see in what module a function
>   is defined. Use exref (Cross Reference
>   Tool) to find module dependencies.

Comment: This is good advice except for perhaps one exception. The math module.