# Opening a module in Erlang

Tags: module, erlang

Is there a way to open a module in Erlang and then call its functions without using module name prefix?
Like opening an ML structure!

Comment: Yes, and beware that it is usually a bad idea. In ML as well as in Erlang. The main problem, short term, is that grep won't work on your code base any more. The problem, in the longer term, is that you end up with a mess of internal knowledge you need to have to code for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
-import(my_module, [foo/1,bar/2]).
```

to import individual functions (in my example `foo/1` and `bar/2`) from another module (`my_module`), see the [modules documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/modules.html) . There is no way of importing *all* functions from a module, they have to be explicitly listed.

Also see [In Erlang how can I import all functions from a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503768/in-erlang-how-can-i-import-all-functions-from-a-module) for an explanation why you shouldn't import functions!

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't! The methods given by @johlo and @stemm are just work-arounds which allow you to not explicitly write the module name but that is all. The `-import(...)` declaration is a misnomer and doesn't do what you would expect.

Given Erlang's very dynamic handling of code it would be practically meaningless as well. There is no guarantee that at run-time you have the same "other" module as you had at compile-time, or if it is there at all. All code handling, compiling/loading/purging/reloading/etc. , is done on a module basis and there are no inter-module dependencies or optimisations.

Comment: Is it the same in ML case? So when we open a structure locally in another ML file, is it just a work-around? I mean from the compiler point of view!

Comment: If you could direct me to some documentation about this, that would be very helpful! :-)

Comment: @AmKh The only thing you can do in Erlang with another module is to call a function in it. The compiler has no knowledge, and assumes nothing, about any other module, this also applies to all modules included in the OTP libraries. **All** checking, both for the existence of the module and of the function, is done at run-time. So when the compiler sees a call to a function in another module all it does it to say "if possible I want to call this function".

Comment: Can't help you with the documentation I'm afraid as I don't know of anywhere where this is explicitly stated. Everything more or less assumes you know and understand this.

Comment: I have seen some BIF calls that don't have the module name as a prefix, so how Erlang compiler handles such calls? How it knows which module the function resides in?

Comment: It knows about some BIFs, usually the oldest and most commonly used, and transforms them to explicit calls into the `erlang` module. So `spawn(...)` becomes `erlang:spawn(...)`. This means you can always prefix BIFs with `erlang:`. It works as if there was a `-import(erlang, [...]).` added to each file. Reloading the module `erlang` with something different would be "interesting". :-)

Comment: In SML, `open` really embeds the code in the scope you are defining. SML doesn't have the dynamic loading problem. if `F.x` is defined in a struct and you `open F` in `structure G` then `G.x` is also defined outside of `G`'s scope. In general, the SML module system is *the* module system to get inspired by. But many people misunderstands it, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of import you can use defining:

```
-define(SIN(X), math:sin(X)).

my_func(X) -> ?SIN(X).
```